# How to handle hyphenated names in powershell when getting active directory info

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to get the password expiration date in active directory using powershell for users with hyphenated names (IE firstname.last-name) and on the hyphenated names it gives an invalid cmdlet error. How do I query the hyphenated names?

The current command I have is

```
net user $username /DOMAIN | find "Password expires"
```

Comment: Have you considered just using ambiguous name resolution? `Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(anr=$username)"`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use the ActiveDirectory module instead of the net commands:

```
$MaxPwdAge = (Get-ADDefaultDomainPasswordPolicy).MaxPasswordAge.Days

Get-ADUser -Filter { Name -like "*-*" } -Properties 'PasswordLastSet', 'DisplayName' |
Select-Object Name,DisplayName,
    @{ Name = 'PasswordExpires'; Expression = { $_.PasswordLastSet.AddDays( $MaxPwdAge ) } }
```

If needed You can change the filter to look at DisplayName instead `-Filter { DisplayName -like "*-*" }`

You may need to adjust the properties you're retrieving depending on what you want to include in the output. This is just an example but it works, and can be used to plot a path forward.  It does seem like you have to calculate the expiration date. But I can work on that and see if there's a better way.

If you want to Query for a specific user:

```
Get-ADUser Name-Name -Properties 'PasswordLastSet',DisplayName |
Select-Object Name,DisplayName,
    @{ Name = 'PasswordExpires'; Expression = { $_.PasswordLastSet.AddDays( $MaxPwdAge ) } }
```

This assumes the Hyphenated name is a samAccountName.  If you need to search by DisplayName you'll have to resort back to filter, even if you are looking for only the one user.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter { DisplayName -eq "Name-Name" } -Properties 'PasswordLastSet',DisplayName |
    Select-Object Name,DisplayName,
        @{ Name = 'PasswordExpires'; Expression = { $_.PasswordLastSet.AddDays( $MaxPwdAge ) } }
```

Note: That you have to change the "Name-Name". Also in the last example I changed to using the `-eq` operator instead of `-like`.  Obviously this assumes you know exactly what you're looking for.  Though you can use `-Like` with DisplayName or even the surName attribute if you like.

Comment: Close, but it still errors out when inputing usernames with a hyphenated last name. I'm taking a csv of usernames as input and when it hits a username with a hyphenated last name it errors.

Comment: My example was to return all users with hyphen in the name property.  I'll add an example if you're looking for a specific user.  Can you please post a copy of the command and resulting error?

Comment: ```
Get-ADUser -Filter { Name -like $usernameS } -Properties 'PasswordLastSet', 'DisplayName' |
    Select-Object Name,DisplayName,
        @{ Name = 'PasswordExpires'; Expression = { $_.PasswordLastSet.AddDays( $MaxPwdAge ) } }
    net user $usernameS /DOMAIN | find "Password expires"
   }```

Comment: ```
Get-ADUser : Cannot find an object with identity: 'firstname.last-name under: 'redacted'.
At C:\Users\user\Desktop\passwordexpire.ps1:16 char:1
+ Get-ADUser firstname.last`-name  -Properties 'PasswordLastSet', 'D ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (firstname.last-name:ADUser) [Get-ADUser], ADIdentityNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityNotFoundException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser
```

Comment: If you are using the `-Like` operator you must use the "*" 's.  If you are querying for more than 1 user you must use something that will match them.  You can't just give a collection as is implied by the plural `$UserNameS`.  Be care ful of that.

Comment: $UserNameS is a single user, it was modified, probably needs a rename. Even ripping out filter and just piping the straight username errors out

Comment: https://gist.github.com/aoighost/67d5aec8517528e27330778f8a3b70d3

Comment: All of these permutations are working for me.  Using `-Like`, `-eq` or directly referencing the samAccountName.  I checked your `-replace` command and that also seems appropriate.  The only thing I don't have to test with is the file you are pulling from.  Obviously with everything working so far, I'd need a sample of that.  You can sanitize the data but please make sure it's true to the format etc...